# How to run app with puppeteer on remote server

Tags: laravel-5, puppeteer

In my laravel 5.8 app I managed to generate file with spatie/browsershot and download it ok, 
but to run it locally at my Ubuntu 18 I had ro run

```
npm i puppeteer@next
```

as I got error :

```
Error Output: ================ module.js:549 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module 'puppeteer' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15) at Function.Module._load
```

This decision I found at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2119 branch.

But after I installed the app at my server  I got error :

```
The command "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin NODE_PATH=`npm root -g` node '/var/www/html/votes/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/../bin/browser.js' '{"url":"file:\/\/\/tmp\/0046339001562826751\/index.html","action":"pdf","options":{"path":"generate_profile_card_ohTcbPxIiVNo5CUp8nIDJHbO8mKU2MhwCq4UFIbB_filename.pdf","args":[],"viewport":{"width":800,"height":600},"displayHeaderFooter":false,"printBackground":true}}'" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: /var/www/html/votes/public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ module.js:549 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module 'puppeteer' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15) at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25) at Module.require (module.js:596:17) at require (internal/module.js:11:18) at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/votes/vendor/spatie/browsershot/bin/browser.js:1:81) at Module._compile (module.js:652:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10) at Module.load (module.js:565:32) at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Installing laravel app I need to run

```
composer install
```

But not

```
npm install
```

Yes ?

But I have to include /public/js/app.js file in /layouts/frontend.blade.php of my template.
I suppose that puppeteer must be in this file?

my composer.json :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "alaouy/youtube": "^2.2",
        "aloha/twilio": "^4.0",
        "arrilot/laravel-widgets": "^3.12",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^4.5",
        "davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "5.x",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.8",
        "elasticquent/elasticquent": "dev-master",
        "facebook/graph-sdk": "^5.7",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.2",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "itsgoingd/clockwork": "^3.0",
        "jrean/laravel-user-verification": "^7.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravelium/sitemap": "^3.1",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "mews/captcha": "^2.2",
        "mews/purifier": "^2.1",
        "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*",
        "proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation": ">2.2.0",
        "s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver": "~2.0",
        "snowfire/beautymail": "dev-master",
        "socialiteproviders/instagram": "^3.0",
        "spatie/browsershot": "^3.27",
        "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^3.1",
        "spatie/laravel-backup": "^6.1",
        "spatie/laravel-feed": "^2.1",
        "spatie/laravel-image-optimizer": "^1.4",
        "spatie/laravel-newsletter": "^4.2",
        "spatie/laravel-sitemap": "^5.3",
        "spatie/laravel-tags": "^2.1",
        "spipu/html2pdf": "^5.2",
        "symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "^1.2",
        "themsaid/laravel-mail-preview": "^2.0",
        "unisharp/laravel-filemanager": "^1.9",
        "wboyz/laravel-enum": "^0.2.1",
        "willvincent/feeds": "1.1.*",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^9.0.0",
        "zendframework/zend-diactoros": "^2.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.1",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "orangehill/iseed": "^2.6",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0",
        "xethron/migrations-generator": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ],


        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan vendor:publish --provider=\"Proengsoft\\JsValidation\\JsValidationServiceProvider\" --tag=public --force"
        ]

    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.16",
        "lodash": "^4.17.11",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.6",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap-colorpicker": "^3.1.2",
        "datatables.net-bs": "^1.10.19",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "jquery-confirm": "^3.3.2",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.5.2",
        "mustache": "^2.3.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    }
}
```

How to fix this error on server(ubuntu 18 inder Digital Ocean) ?